# Script to remove first line from all the text files in a directory

Tags: perl

I'm trying to write a Perl script which reads all the text files in a directory and writes all the lines except first to a separate file. If there are 3 files, I want the script to read all those 3 files and write 3 new files with same lines except the first. This is what I wrote.. but when I try to run the script, it executes fine with no errors but doesn't do the work it is supposed to. Can someone please look into it?

```
opendir (DIR, "dir\\") or die "$!";
my @files = grep {/*?\.txt/}  readdir DIR;
close DIR;
my $count=0;
my $lc;
foreach my $file (@files) {
   $count++;
   open(FH,"dir\\$file") or die "$!";
   $str="dir\\example_".$count.".txt";
   open(FH2,">$str");
   $lc=0;
   while($line = <FH>){
        if($lc!=0){
            print FH2 $line;
        }
        $lc++;
    }
   close(FH);
   close(FH2);
}
```

And the second file doesn't exists, it is supposed to be created by script.

Comment: It works for me, but I had to quote the `*` in the second line. Do you really have a directory named `dir`, and is your path separator `\\`?

Comment: @EmilioSilva- Thanks, that was the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing these lines

```
opendir (DIR, "dir\\") or die "$!";
...
close DIR;
```

to

```
opendir (DIR, "dir") or die "$!";
...
closedir DIR;
```

I tried running your code locally and the only two issues I had were with the directory name containing the trailing slash and trying to use the filehandle close() function on a dirhandle.

Comment: Thanks that was close, the other issue was unquoted *.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the list of files ...

```
foreach my $file ( @files ) {
  open my $infile , '<' , "dir/$file" or die "$!" ;
  open my $outfile , '>' , "dir/example_" . ++${counter} . '.txt' or die "$!" ;
  <$infile>; # Skip first line.
  while( <$infile> ) {
    print $outfile $_ ;
  }
}
```

The lexical filehandles will be closed automatically when going out of scope.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you're using $count here, as that's going to just turn a list of files like:

```
01.txt
bob.txt
alice.txt
02.txt
```

into:

```
01_1.txt
bob_2.txt
alice_3.txt
02_4.txt
```

Keep in mind, @files isn't being sorted, so it will return in the order the files exist in the directory table. If you were to delete and re-create the file 01.txt, it would be moved to the end of the list, re-ordering the whole set:

```
bob_1.txt
alice_2.txt
02_3.txt
01_4.txt
```

Since that wasn't really part of your original question, this does exactly what you asked to do:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
while(<*.txt>) { # for every file in the *.txt glob from the current directory
    open(IN, $_) or die ("Cannot open $_: $!"); # open file for reading
    my @in = <IN>; # read the contents into an array
    close(IN); # close the file handle
    shift @in; # remove the first element from the array

    open(OUT, ">$_.new") or die ("Cannot open $_.new: $!"); # open file for writing
    print OUT @in; # write the contents of the array to the file
    close(OUT); # close the file handle
}
```